# Waht's the error of minimize function

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, minimize

I was studying taxicab distance with minimize() function in scipy module. And this is the source code of that in 'Ipython Notebook Essentials'.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import scipy.optimize

points = np.array([[10.3, 15.4], [6.5, 8.8], [15.6, 10.3], [4.7, 12.8]])

def make_txmin(points):
    def txmin_func(p):
        return sum(np.abs(points - p))
    return txmin_func

txmin = make_txmin(points)
x0 = np.array([0., 0.])
res = scipy.optimize.minimize(txmin, x0 , method='nelder-mead',options={'xtol': 1e-5, 'disp':True})
```

I run this source code and then I got an error like this;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/IPython/chapter4/taxicab distance.py", line 15, in <module>
    res = scipy.optimize.minimize(txmin, x0 , method='nelder-mead',options={'xtol': 1e-5, 'disp':True})
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minimize.py", line 435, in minimize
    return _minimize_neldermead(fun, x0, args, callback, **options)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 439, in _minimize_neldermead
    fsim[0] = func(x0)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Please tell me what is the problem in this code and what do I have to do.

Comment: Try to check if `sum(np.abs(points -p))` really returns a single value. I remember that `sum(np.array)` sometimes summerized along a specific axis which I was not aware of.

Comment: Replace `sum` with `np.sum` in the function definition

Comment: Thank you, Thank you!!! I solve this problem. Thank you, guys.